# Was Shadorian Civilization technologically advanced?

Tags: one-piece

This question pertains to One Piece.

> I know that Skypians, Birkans, and Shandorians came from the moon. But they should've been technologically advanced right? But Shandorians like Calgara seem to be a small tribe with zero knowledge of poneglyphs etc. Also, they seem to believe in rituals/superstition etc even though they were once an advanced civilization that lived on the moon. Also, they seem way too backward in terms of science and technology. How did that happen?

Also if that's true, then are Poneglyphs a way to find out the story about earth or moon?

Comment: Well, we see a lot of post-apocalyptic movies that people lost touch with technology and are now very dumb and superstitious. so the seeing a small tribe with no knowledge might be logical. after all running out of resources on the moon is an apocalypse for people who live there.

Comment: But still they should've had the technology to come to earth and also two of three races ended up inhabiting sky, while the other race ended up inhabiting jaya. To do that, one would obviously need some kind of tech right? But Calgara's people were just good warriors, even they didn't know why they had the city of gold or who created that gold etc?

Comment: It is possible that only one race had the tech and lent it to others

Comment: @posixKing You don't seem to know how knowledge transfer works. I recommend reading Dr. Stone to get an idea why they could have lost technology

Comment: As for the Poneglyphs, they preserve the dark history. If the moon races play a role in that, then they will be mentioned. The Poneglyphs don't necessarily tell a chronological story.

Comment: The moon has had a significant impact in DB, Na/Boruto; I think it is gonna be a big thing in OP too.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Was the ancient Shandorian civilization technologically advanced? Likely although not confirmed.

To understand the ancient Shandorian civilization there's a lot of lore that needs to be understood about the One Piece timeline, the moon peoples, their successors and the void century.

Over the course of the cover story "[Enel's Great Space Operations](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Enel%27s_Great_Space_Operations)" spanning Ch 428-474 we learn of the ancient moon civilization, the Birkans including their history, impressive technology and the reason they eventually had to leave. To summarize, long ago there was a civilization of winged moon people called the Birkans whose technological feats included sentient robots and ships capable of interplanetary travel. Running out of resources on the moon they used these aforementioned ships to carry them down to the White sea with one particular group making it all the way down to the Blue sea.

[image: Birkans leave the moon]

The descendants of the moon people can be identified by the wings on their backs which include the White sea civilizations of [Skypiea](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Skypiea) and [Birka](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Birka) (Enel's homeland, not to be confused with the ancient moon civilization), and the Blue sea Shandorian civilization on the island of Jaya. When did the moon people come down to the Blue sea? We do not know exactly but according to the tombstone for the city of Shandora Robin translates in Ch 261

[image: Rise and Fall of Shandora]

the city of Shandora prospered in the year 402 (~1100 years ago) meaning it was settled by the moon people some time before then and fell ~800 years ago which places its fall around the tail end of the Void Century. In Ch 272 Robin translates some text inside the city of Shandora written in the language of the Poneglyphs,

[image: Erasure of Shandorian history]

The text refers to how the city of Shandora fought to protect its Poneglyph against an enemy and as a result, their civilization was destroyed and their history erased. While some people survived and became the [Shandians](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Shandia) the Shandorian civilization was gone, their golden city fell to ruin and their history and literature was lost in the void.

Speaking of the void and the fall of Shandora, what happened in the Void Century? I have no idea and that's kind of the point, just about nobody knows what happened in the Void Century. What we do know is that it was a period of history that started ~900 years ago and lasted around 100 years. While historical records exist of the time before and after the Void Century, what happened during these hundred years can only be found on the Poneglyphs. Researching the Poneglyphs/Void Century is forbidden by the World Government and punishable by death. In Ch 395, Professor Clover of Ohara reveals a basic overview of what he thinks happened,

[image: The Void Century]

We do not know if the great civilization he was referring to was Shandora but we do know the World Government is entirely capable of suppressing all knowledge of a once great civilization and that Shandora fell during this time. Meaning Shandora was once a powerful civilization and may or may not have been technologically advanced but due to being erased from history we CANNOT know if this was the case.

In the main story of One Piece, in the year 1122 (~400 years ago and 400 years after the fall of Shandora) we are introduced to the Shandians through the first hand accounts of Mont Blanc Noland (Ch 287-293). The Shandians are descendants of the Shandorians but are a rather low tech society bearing none of the hallmarks of the ancient Birkan civilization (robots and flying ships). They live in a village quite far away from the ruins of Shandora. In 1127, they are launched along with half of Jaya by the [Knock Up Stream](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Knock_Up_Stream) into the White sea island of Skypiea.

One thing to note is that while the Shandian's don't seem to have much of the moon people technology, Enel's flying ship he uses to reach the moon is reminiscent of the moon peoples ship and given he's from Birka they may have had the blueprints/knowledge of interplanetary ships inherited from the moon people.

Answer (score 0):

### My theory

The Shadorians were a tribal race launched into the very sky by a strange Grand Line current known as the "Knockup Stream." They were soon attacked for their land by the Skypian Warriors. The Shandorians were unprepared as they weren't as technically advanced as the Warriors of Skypiea. But they had more combat experience. Despite the leader of the Shandorians, Kalgara, terrible death at the hands of the Warriors, the war still ended in a tie with all Skypian Warriors dying or being stolen by Eneru/Enel/Kami but the Shandorians never got back Shandora. Fast forwards a few years and the Skypian Warriors are back with a more powerful Leader, ensuing a new war. Then, after centuries of this sky battle, Luffy and Company appear, starting the Skypiean saga we all know and love. Their use of dials wer just stolen equipment from their enemy used in a way only for combat.

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about the Shandorians post-knockup stream but rather pre-knockup stream since the Shandorians in Kalgara and Nolan's time 400 years ago were already a very low tech society. I'd want to double check the references but according to the wiki the original prosperous Shandorian society of moon refugees was founded over a millennium ago and fell apart following the events of the void century 8-900 years ago which would explain why the Shandorians we meet lack their historical advanced tech

Comment: They didn't even know that the trees were slowly killing them at the time. They thought it was an act of God. They worshipped SNAKES for frick's sake. They sacrificed the "prettiest" women they could find. WHY WOULD THEY BE TECHNOLOGICALLY ADVANCED BEFORE THE KNOCK-UP STREAM? Also, SINCE WHEN WAS THE WIKI A CREDIBLE SOURCE? I depend on theories that make sense or actual confirmation of theories by the creators. The wiki is just a bunch of theory as well except for the parts that were confirmed in the manga/anime. (petition to make anime non-canon and for the real deal to be the mangas. pwease)

Comment: The wiki isn't a credible source on its own but it makes reference to the relevant bits in the manga which are credible sources. Like I said, I wanted to double check the manga references but I only half finished my answer (research is time consuming ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯) and then forgot about it. Thanks for the reminder :)